# Is my understanding of the refinement of this partition correct?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-explanation, uniform-convergence

I'm reading a proof that a function is jump continuous if and only if there is a sequence of staircase functions that converges uniformly to it.

> [image]

Here $I=[\alpha,\beta] \subseteq \mathbb R$. The author said that

> Now we select a refinement $\mathfrak{Z}_{1}=\left(\xi_{0}, \ldots, \xi_{k}\right)$ of $\mathfrak{Z}_{0}$ with
> $$
> \|f(s)-f(t)\|<1 / n \text { for } s, t \in\left(\xi_{j-1}, \xi_{j}\right) \text { and } j=1, \ldots, k
> $$

Could you please verify if my understanding of how to define $\mathfrak{Z}_{1}$ is correct?

> From the definition of jump continuous functions, we have $\lim_{s \to x^-} f(s) =a$ and $\lim_{s \to x^+} f(s)=b$ exist. This means there exist $\alpha(x),\beta(x)$ such that $\alpha(x) \le s < x$ implies $|f(s)-a| < 1/(2n)$ and that $x < s \le \beta(x)$ implies $|f(s)-b| < 1/(2n)$.
>
> As such, $|f(s)-f(t)| \le |f(s)-a|+|f(t)-a| < 1/(2n)+1/(2n) = 1/n$ for all $s,t \in [\alpha(x),x)$. Similarly, $|f(s)-f(t)| \le |f(s)-b|+|f(t)-b| < 1/(2n)+1/(2n) = 1/n$ for all $s,t \in (x,\beta(x)]$.
>
> Then we define a refinement $$\mathfrak{Z}_{1} = \{x_j \mid 0 \le j \le m\} \cup \{\alpha(x_j) \mid 0 \le j \le m\} \cup \{\beta(x_j) \mid 0 \le j \le m\}$$

Comment: Not much of a help, but most real-analysts refer to such a function as "regulated" rather than "jump continuous."   If you enlarge your search you can find other versions of this proof.  (I don't like "staircase" much either.)

Comment: Since no-one is answering, your refinement is correct.  Often Heine-Borel proofs of these elementary analysis facts offer the worst and messiest way to construct a proof.  The only advantage is that you can use this argument in much more general situations, unlike proofs that use nested-intervals or the Cousin covering lemma.

Comment: Thank you for your verification @B.S.Thomson :) You are totally correct about the authors' intention, which is *In this book, we have tried to lay a solid foundation for analysis on which the reader will be able to build in later forays into modern mathematics. Thus most concepts and definitions are presented, right from the beginning, in their general form — the form which is used in later investigations and in applications. This way the reader needs to learn each concept only once, and then with this basis, can progress directly to more advanced mathematics.*

Comment: By the way, I'm very pleased to meet you @B.S.Thomson :) I very appreciate your kindness in letting your analysis textbooks free.

Comment: For your reference, my textbook is Analysis I by Amann and Escher.